# Extending Euler's Theorem gives minus 1 - why?

Tags: congruences, totient-function

Euler's Theorem states that for some coprimes $n$ and $a$:
$a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod  n$

Example: $ a = 10, p=7, q=11, n=p*q=77,  \phi(n) =(p-1)*(q-1)= 60$

$10^{60} \equiv 1 \mod 77$

When I take the left-hand side to the power of $x$, then I would assume that I also need to take the right-hand side to the power of $x$, e.g.,

$(a^{\phi(n)})^x \equiv 1^x \mod n$

And then the right-hand side is always $+1$, because $1^x = 1$ for every $x$.

However, sometimes the result is $-1$, e.g. for $x=1/4$:

$(10^{60})^{(1/4)} \equiv 76 \equiv -1 \mod 77$

Can somebody please explain me why (and when) this is the case? Thanks.

Background: I need this for the last step to understand the proof of the following:

$(a^{\phi(n)})^{(1/4)} * a \equiv \pm a \mod n$

I think Euler's Theorem is needed here (?). So I assume that $(a^{\phi(n)})^{(1/4)} \equiv \pm 1 \mod n$, but why is it sometimes $-1$?

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with congruences and Euler's theorem, the same paradox comes up in ordinary arithmetic: $(-1)^4=1$, so $(-1)^{4x}=1^x=1$; but if we set $x=\frac14$ this becomes $-1=1$. What gives??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really have to do with Euler's theorem specifically. Rather, it is a general issue with fractional powers in modular arithmetic (or just arithmetic in general, as bof points out). You're not really allowed to raise to fractional powers. You can do it if the result is an integer, but you may have to add a plus-or-minus sign (if the power has even demoninator). This is similar to how the solutions in the real numbers to

$$x^2 = 1$$

are $$x=1  \qquad \text{and} \qquad x=-1$$

---

For example:

$$4\equiv 9 \pmod{5}$$

but

$$\sqrt{4} \not\equiv \sqrt{9} \pmod{5} \qquad \text{because} \qquad 2 \not\equiv 3 \pmod{5}$$

You can get away with this if you are careful with the minus sign

$$\sqrt{4} \equiv - \sqrt{9} \pmod{5} \qquad \text{because} \qquad 2 \equiv -3\pmod{5}$$

Comment: So I could say: if $x \equiv y \mod n$, then $x^z \equiv \pm y^z \mod n$ for every $z$, such that $x^z$ and $y^z$ is an integer?

Comment: @neuteich I think that is correct.

Comment: @neuteich That is not correct in general. For example let $x=2^3$, $y=1^3$. $x\equiv y\pmod7$, but $1=x^{1/3}\not\equiv\pm\,y^{1/3}=\pm\,2\pmod7$. One really has to be careful with fractional exponents (and not only in modular arithmetic, as Zubin pointed out in his answer).

Comment: @barto Hmm. Is it correct in general for even-denominator powers then?

Comment: Not always, for example $1^4\equiv2^4\pmod{15}$, but $1\not\equiv\pm\,2\pmod{15}$. There are many counterexamples. What is true is the following:$$\text{If }n\in\mathbb N^\times,\;\gcd(x,n)=1,\;\gcd(y,n)=1\text{ and }z=\frac pq\text{ with}\gcd(q,\varphi(n))=1,\text{ then }\\x\equiv y\pmod n\text{ implies }x^z\equiv y^z\pmod n \text{ (provided }x^z,y^z\in\mathbb Z).$$
The conditions $\gcd(xy,n)=1$ and $\gcd(q,\varphi(n))=1$ can not be omitted. In fact the following is true: we can take $q$th roots in $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$ if and only if $\gcd(q,\varphi(n))=1$.

Comment: @barto Is there a theorem (or something similar) that states what you have just written, or does it "simply" follow from some arithmetic rules (as you have written it)? Many thanks!

Comment: @barto in the last step, it must be "implies $x^z \equiv \pm y^z \mod n$", doesn't it?

Comment: @neuteich no, since we require $\gcd(q,\varphi(n))=1$. In particular since $\varphi(n)$ is even for $n>2$ $q$ can not be even, so the case of 'square roots' need not be considered.

Comment: A proof of that result concerning $q$th roots modulo $n$: Note (since we require that $x^{1/q},y^{1/q}\in\mathbb Z$) that it is equivalent to prove that $a^q\equiv b^q$ implies $a\equiv b$ for $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, $\gcd(ab,n)=1$. Because $\gcd(q,\varphi(n))=1$ there exists $r$ s.t. $qr\equiv1\pmod{\varphi(n)}$, say $qr=1+k\varphi(n)$. Hence $$a^q\equiv b^q\implies a^{qr}\equiv b^{qr}\implies a^{1+k\varphi(n)}\equiv b^{1+k\varphi(n)}\implies a\equiv b\pmod n$$ (where the last step uses Euler's theorem: $a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv b^{\varphi(n)}\equiv1$).

Comment: Ok, but in my example it is $\phi(n) = 60$, $q=4$ and $gcd(4,60) = 4 \neq 1$, and the result is $\equiv -1 \mod n$. In particular it is still not clear for me, why $-a$ is also a result of the following: $(a^{\phi(n)})^{1/4} * a \equiv \pm a \mod n$. Using fractional powers, one cannot say if it is $+a$ or $-a$ and thus simply has to be careful and say $\pm a$?

Answer (score 0):

$10\equiv-1\pmod{11}$

Again, $10\equiv3\pmod7\implies10^3\equiv3^3\equiv-1$

$\implies10^{\text{lcm}(1,3)}\equiv-1\pmod{\text{lcm}(7,11)}$

i.e., $10^3\equiv-1\pmod{77}$

So, $10^{3(2r+1)}\equiv(-1)^{2r+1}\equiv-1\pmod{77}$ where integer $r\ge0$